# JQuery not working in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

For some reason i can't seem to het jQuery to work in my asp.net page

I have sourced the jQuery library but the document.ready function never fires

i have also tried the window.load function as

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Page</title>
<script src="script/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('works');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body">

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Comment: your code looks fine .... validate the link to jquery library

Answer (score 8):

There is a `"` in the `<body">` tag

Answer (score 6):

Script tags should be closed like this:

```
 <script src="script/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you didn't set up the script path correctly. To check that I would try importing Google hosted jQuery first.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and also you really need to explicitly close the `</script>` tag

Answer (score 1):

Once I have the same problem but when I use google ajax api it works for me. Try it

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />
```